# How can we start the webflow based on some condition?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow version 2.2.1.RELEASE. and below is my action state, when i type the url as //hostAddress:8080/app/order the flow starts by executing the below action state. My question is there any way to pass parameter to this action state? or can we call the below action state when clicked on some button by passing one parameter. because the flow starts from below action state.

```
<action-state id="placeInitialize">
    <evaluate expression="orderActions.setupPlacePage"></evaluate>
    <transition on="error" to="home" />
    <transition on="success" to="estimate" />
</action-state>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this inside your flow (it will be your entry point):

```
<input name="param1" type="string" />

<decision-state id="isParamSet">
    <if test="param1 == null" then="estimate" else="error" />
</decision-state>
```

and then just call you flow with `//hostAddress:8080/app/order?param1=something`